# Using Xcode UI tests to test underlying framework behavior

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ios-frameworks

I am building an iOS framework that collects information about various events in an iOS app and performs local and remote analysis. Some of these events can't be tested outside of an app: for example, view controller transitions. To test these events, I built a test iOS app and would like to use Xcode UI tests to:

- Initiate a view controller transition by, say, tapping a button that pushes a VC to a navigation controller, or by switching to a different tab in a tab controller
- Verify that the framework was able to detect the view controller transitions and generate the necessary events (e.g., send them to the server)

The problem is that Xcode UI tests run outside the app, so I can't access any shared objects to verify that the framework is functioning properly. I also can't insert any mock objects, because, again, I don't have access to the framework loaded in the app's process.

I went as far as trying to load the framework in a kind of test mode and have it update a label with some results that the UI test would then be able to read. But even that is difficult, because `XCUIElement` doesn't give me the actual text of the element; I can only query for elements with some predefined text. I can sort of work with that, but it seems like a very roundabout approach for something that should be rather trivial.

Are there any better alternatives for testing events that can only be simulated in a running app, and then verifying that my framework was able to detect and process them? In addition to view controller transitions, I am also interested in touch interactions, accelerometer events, and other features that can't be simulated outside of an app. Naturally, I can simulate these events for unit testing, but I would also like to automatically test that when these events occur in an actual app, the proper responses are generated in my framework.

Comment: Have you considered UI tests for the touch events and transitions? May be a better choice than unit tests depending on what you are after.

Comment: @Robert: I am talking about UI tests, not unit tests. I want to use UI tests to tap a button which triggers a VC transition and then see the effects of that transition not on the UI elements, but rather on my framework's internal components.

Comment: Are you aware that iOS Unit Tests (XCTest) are actually launching the application? You could create "semi" UI tests in that you you wouldn't be emulating user events, rather directly calling the methods that provoke the transitions.

Comment: @OhadSchneider: Yep, but that's not what I want. I want to test the actual UI transitions, accelerometer events, taps, and so on. I also have unit tests of course, and they test the logic in isolation. What you're proposing is somewhere down the middle and I wouldn't want to invest in it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [SBTUITestTunnel](https://github.com/Subito-it/SBTUITestTunnel). This library extends the functionality of UI Tests adding some features that might come in handy in cases like yours.

**Network monitoring**

The library allows your test target to collect network calls invoked in the app. Usage is pretty straight forward:

```
func testThatNetworkAfterEvent() {
  // Use SBTUITunneledApplication instead of XCUIApplication
  let app = SBTUITunneledApplication()
  app.launchTunnelWithOptions([SBTUITunneledApplicationLaunchOptionResetFilesystem]) {
      // do additional setup before the app launches
      // i.e. prepare stub request, start monitoring requests
  }

  app.monitorRequestsWithRegex("(.*)myserver(.*)") // monitor all requests containing myserver

  // 1. Interact with UI tapping elements that generate your events

  // 2. Wait for events to be sent. This could be determined from the UI (a UIActivitiIndicator somewhere in your app?) or ultimately if you have no other option with an NSThread.sleepfortimeinterval

  // 3. Once ready flush calls and get the list of requests
  let requests: [SBTMonitoredNetworkRequest] = app.monitoredRequestsFlushAll()

  for request in requests {
      let requestBody = request.request!.HTTPBody // HTTP Body in POST request?
      let responseJSON = request.responseJSON
      let requestTime = request.requestTime // How long did the request take?
  }
}
```

The nice thing of the network monitoring is that all the testing code and logic is contained in your test target.

**Custom block of code**

There are other use cases where you need to perform custom code to be conveniently invoked in the test target, you can do that as well.

Register a block of code in the app target

```
SBTUITestTunnelServer.registerCustomCommandNamed("myCustomCommandKey") {
    injectedObject in
    // this block will be invoked from app.performCustomCommandNamed()

    return "any object you like"
}
```

and invoke it from the test target

```
func testThatNetworkAfterEvent() {
  let app = ....

  // at the right time
  let objFromBlock = app.performCustomCommandNamed("myCustomCommand", object: someObjectToInject)
}
```

<s>Currently you can only inject data from the test target -> app target. If you need the other way around, you could store that data in the NSUserDefaults and fetch it using the SBTUIApplication's `userDefaultsObjectForKey()` method.</s>

I personally don't like the idea of mixing standard and test code in your app's target, so I'd advise to use this only when really needed.

**EDIT**

I've update the library and starting from vision 0.9.23 you can now pass back any object from the block to the test target. No need for workarounds anymore!

Comment: Just to clarify re "the other way around" -- can I use `registerCustomCommandNamed` to retrieve data from, say, a singleton object in the framework that's loaded into the test app?

Comment: Looks like the answer is yes. Thanks -- this is pretty much exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an automated way to have things done, but do use breakpoints as an intermediate way, at least until you get things started automatically. You can add a symbolic breakpoint to hit on UI methods such as [UIWindow setRootViewController:], viewWillAppear, etc.

You can explicitly define modules, conditions and actions, so that whenever someone views your VC, some action will be done that might be helpful to you.

If you can print something from your framework using a simple "po myEvent" upon some viewDidAppear, you're good to go. I've never tried using fancier methods as an action, but those can be done as well.

Comment: Sure, I can use breakpoints and step through the code to do manual testing. I am not a big fan though. I really want this to happen automatically.